# Python (BeautfiulSoup4) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

[cmd screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHfOM.png)

I am using Microsoft Windows 11 Pro.
My python version is: 3.11.4 and my pip version is:23.1.2

I have downloaded beautifulsoup by using cmd but when ı want to run the following code ı get an error.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

> File "C:\Users\koray\PycharmProjects\p4eproject\deneme.py", line 2, in 
> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Can you guys please help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried running your script from the commandline (same cmd you used to call `pip`)? Possibly your IDE comes with its own version of python and isn't using your systems one.